# Mysql Transaction It is possible on deleting file php?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, try-catch, unlink

On Yii1 This is DB Transaction Assuming I have $model1 and $model2 object to be saved.

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
try{

    if(!$model1->save()) throw new CDbException("Error: fail to save model1"); // successfuly save
    if(!$model2->save()) throw new CDbException("Error: fail to save model2"); // If this one throws an error it will go to catch then roll back the previous one w/c the $model1 

    $transaction->commit();

}catch(Exception $ex){

    $transaction->rollback();
}
```

My question is on deleting files in PHP is possible to adapt the idea of SQL transaction?

```
try{

    unlink("file1.txt"); //this is successfully deleted
    unlink("file2.txt"); //failed to delete this one how can I rollback the file1?

}catch(Exception $ex) {

    //need to rollback the file1 or any file has been deleted or modify on try{}
}
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes, but its not as simple as it is with a database as MYSQL does all the heavy lifting for you, while with file deletes you have to do it mandraulically

Comment: Is there a class or function exist to do this one ? or i really need to do it from scratch.

Comment: I dont know of one, but google may be your friend in this situation

Comment: I'm already looking for some ideas or class/function to do this, but no luck, I have an idea, but a lot of code/logic to be written if I do it. The reason why I ask this question here, maybe there is someone here already did or know a class for this one.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you so much for your comment.